# form helper dropdown fine tune

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using form_dropdown in one form with the following options:

```
<select name="depto">
<option value="">[todos los departamentos]</option>
<option value="0001">First</option>
<option value="01">Second</option>
</select>
```

When the field has any value different of empty, that is "0001" or "01", in both cases the form_dropdown generates

```
<select name="depto">
<option value="">[todos los departamentos]</option>
<option selected="selected" value="0001">First</option>
<option selected="selected" value="01">Second</option>
</select>
```

marking as selected the 2 options.

Looking inside the forms helper, the in_array() function is used to check the value.

I changed the form_helper to call in_array() using exact matching, that is the third parameter as 'true' and started working as spected.

Do you see any problems with that change?
The small changes are marked with `/// HERE THE ,true ADDED`

Here is the code of the function:

```
/**
 * Drop-down Menu
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @param   array
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('form_dropdown'))
{
    function form_dropdown($name = '', $options = array(), $selected = array(), $extra = '')
    {
        if ( ! is_array($selected))
        {
            $selected = array($selected);
        }

        // If no selected state was submitted we will attempt to set it automatically
        if (count($selected) === 0)
        {
            // If the form name appears in the $_POST array we have a winner!
            if (isset($_POST[$name]))
            {
                $selected = array($_POST[$name]);
            }
        }

        if ($extra != '') $extra = ' '.$extra;

        $multiple = (count($selected) > 1 && strpos($extra, 'multiple') === FALSE) ? ' multiple="multiple"' : '';

        $form = '<select name="'.$name.'"'.$extra.$multiple.">\n";

        foreach ($options as $key => $val)
        {
            $key = (string) $key;

            if (is_array($val))
            {
                $form .= '<optgroup label="'.$key.'">'."\n";

                foreach ($val as $optgroup_key => $optgroup_val)
                {
                    $sel = (in_array($optgroup_key, $selected, true)) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; /// HERE THE ,true added

                    $form .= '<option value="'.$optgroup_key.'"'.$sel.'>'.(string) $optgroup_val."</option>\n";
                }

                $form .= '</optgroup>'."\n";
            }
            else
            {
                $sel = (in_array($key, $selected, true)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';  /// HERE THE ,true ADDED

                $form .= '<option value="'.$key.'"'.$sel.'>'.(string) $val."</option>\n";
            }
        }

        $form .= '</select>';

        return $form;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not having used codeigniter, this is a random guess(so not answering).  But PHP handles numbers that begin with 0 as binary numbers.  That means that 01 is equal to 1.  I'd imagine the same applies to 0001 as it is also 1 in binary.

Comment: can we see your `form_dropdown()` code?  with raw values please.

Comment: Sorry, english is not one of my strongest points. You mean CI's form_dropdown() changed code? or the code where i call it?

Comment: @jondavidjohn `$depto = $this-input->post('depto');
    ......
    $deptolist = array( '0001' => 'First',
                        '01' => 'Second' 
                        );
    [in view]                    
    echo form_dropdown('depto', $deptolist, $depto);
`

Comment: I agree with Logan. Could you use values that are more different? Also, you shouldn't change the core ci classes. It's a much better idea to extend the class and make your changes in a new class. @Logan, write your comment as an answer so it can be accepted!

Comment: @musoNic: No, those values came from the user, and 01 and 0001 are defferent. The Logan's answer is the known problem, the question is if the solution taken can produce problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your values as strings like the examples below and see if that works.

```
$deptolist = array( (string)'0001' => 'First', (string)'01' => 'Second' );
```